# Where to save data on a windows phone?

Tags: io, windows-phone

When you need to create a file, it asks for a path. How do I determine that path? When you simply type "Data", does it create a file named "Data" in your application's directory? Thank you.

Comment: Look up IsolatedStorage and all its friends

Comment: I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createfile(v=vs.105).aspx) which also asks for a path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the path simply do this:

```
tempStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
```

then to create file "rectemp.json" in that path:

```
tempStore.CreateFile("rectemp.json");
```

this will create the file in IsolatedStorage which is the storage area for your app.